# Can Hepatitis be caused by Bacteria?

Tags: human-biology, bacteriology, hepatitis

There are many information about viral hepatitis. But it is interesting for me, can bacteria cause the hepatitis too?

Comment: Short answer: Yes , they can. Have a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hepatitis) Wikipedia article.

Comment: @Chris - I would disagree; I couldn't find any mention of hepatitis from bacteria in your linked source. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Look under causes, there you will find the following: "Less commonly some bacterial, parasitic, fungal, mycobacterial and protozoal infections can cause hepatitis." Since a Hepatitis only describes the inflammation of the liver, anything what can cause this causes a hepatitis. You could also have a look [here](http://www.expertconsultbook.com/expertconsult/ob/book.do?method=display&type=bookPage&decorator=none&eid=4-u1.0-B978-1-4377-0881-3..00036-X--s0050&isbn=978-1-4377-0881-3).

Comment: Hepatitis just means liver inflammation. The word per se does not indicate any causative agent.

Answer (score 5):

Hepatitis is a condition of the liver where the cells of the liver organ are inflamed. Most often it is caused by a viral infection, hepatitis [A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hepatitis_A), [B](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hepatitis_B) and [C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hepatitis_C) are all viral forms of the disease.

Bacteria (and Fungi) can cause hepatitis of the liver, and two examples would be the [Staphylococcal and Streptococcal bacteria](http://www.expertconsultbook.com/expertconsult/ob/book.do?method=display&type=bookPage&decorator=none&eid=4-u1.0-B978-1-4377-0881-3..00036-X--s0050&isbn=978-1-4377-0881-3). These can directly infect the liver, and are also responsible for some inflammations in other tissues of the [skin and heart](http://www.medicinejournal.co.uk/article/S1357-3039(06)00189-7/abstract) and elsewhere.

Prolonged alcohol abuse is another cause of hepatitis (as well as cirrhosis) and is not associated with bacteria virus or fungi, but instead from a damaging effect on the liver.

Comment: [Helicobacter hepaticus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicobacter_hepaticus) is suspected to cause hepatitis.

Comment: Thanks @inf3rno you could add that in as a second answer

Comment: I don't want to, I don't think it is enough for an answer, maybe to an edit...

Comment: http://europepmc.org/abstract/MED/11677423

Comment: Hepatitis has two definitions: inflammation of the liver in general, or inflammation of the liver due to one of several viruses.  The viruses are, of course, viral.  However hepatitis can also mean the symptom of an inflamed liver.  That symptom can be caused by bacteria.

Answer (score 3):

The suffix '*-itis*' (*-ῖτις*, in ancient greek) usually is added to a word to represent a pathological condition called inflammation.

So, **haepatitis** (or hepatitis) means generically inflammation of liver (*ἧπαρ* épar, in ancient greek).
Usually it is  [caused by viruses](http://www.who.int/topics/hepatitis/en/)  such as HAV, HBV, and HCV.

An haepatitis can be due also to  [toxic agents or be autoimmune](http://accessmedicine.mhmedical.com/content.aspx?bookid=331&sectionid=40727101) .

But, whaterver it is the cause of inflammation of liver cell, it is called haepatites; even if it is caused by less common pathogens as [bacteria; protists like *T Gondii* ; minor hepatotropic viruses, like EBV, CMV, and herpetic viruses in general](http://accessmedicine.mhmedical.com/content.aspx?bookid=331&sectionid=40727101); [fungi](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2007764), or [protozoa and other parasites](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/9781119950509.ch39/summary).

Bacteria can cause haepatitis, examples would be the Staphylococcal and Streptococcal haepatitis.

Ever the excessive intake of table salt (Na-Cl) or cronic alcoholism may cause  haepatitis or even a liver's cirrhosis.

So, though it is less common, but [bacteria may cause haepatitis](http://europepmc.org/abstract/MED/11677423).